# NEO4J - Retrieve uni directional relationship between nodes

Tags: neo4j, cql

Imagine I have 2 nodes A & B where relation from

> A -> B is x

and relation from

> B -> A is y

Is there a way where I can get just the outgoing relations from A ?

Like I need a CQL when asked for `A -> B` , gives me only `x`

**EDIT:**

I'm looking for a query which gives me relation from `A -> B` (only), not from `B-> A`

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do this to match all outgoing relations from A:

```
Match (A:yourLabel{yourProperty: theValue})-[r]->(B) return r
```

This will return all the outgoint relations from A.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response, 
This query returns all the relations between A & B where I just need relation from A -> B (I don't need relations from B -> A)

Comment: No, this will return the outgoing relations from A, so you only get A->B not B->A.

Comment: Thank You :) My fault, I put same name to both the relations, hence it's returning me A -> B & B -> A